# How to count when string value filtered by A is also equal to string value filtered by B

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am currently working in Power BI and need to write the DAX code for counting number of string values when string filtered by A is also appearing when same string filtered by B.

I have tried various of codes and everything that came in my mind, but I am lacking experience in comparing values in DAX, and kinda beat at the moment.

eg.
[image]

When looking at table, I need to count (distinct) when John, Adam, Julie from A is also appearing in B, which is in this case is 3.

I will be happy if someone has any ideas or directions for me to seek into!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table name is "Data":

```
 Count of Common Names   =
    VAR A_Names =
        CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Data[Name] ), Data[Filter] = "A" )
    VAR B_Names =
        CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Data[Name] ), Data[Filter] = "B" )
    VAR Common_Names =
        INTERSECT ( A_Names, B_Names )
    RETURN
        COUNTROWS ( Common_Names )
```

How it works:
First, we create a table of distinct names for filter A.
Second, we do the same for filter B.
Finally, we find what names exist in both tables, by finding their intersection.

**Edit:**

To calculate costs for common names, modify the above measure:

```
Cost of A given B =
VAR A_Names =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Data[Name] ), Data[Filter] = "A" )
VAR B_Names =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Data[Name] ), Data[Filter] = "B" )
VAR Common_Names =
    INTERSECT ( A_Names, B_Names )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Data[Cost] ), Common_Names, Data[Filter] = "A" )
```

Comment: Nice, really appreciate your help!  I have another question to be honest. Lets say in the table, there was an another column called "Cost" which holds different value in each row. I need to sum the cost in A for the names if it is in A AND B,   

e.g if John in A costed 10$, Adam in A costed 15$, John in B costed 5$, Adam in B costed 10$,  Sum of Cost in A relative to B is 10+15$ = 25$  

How can I sum the cost of the names appearing in A which also appears in B ?

Comment: See the edit. As a side note, it's usually a good idea to include all relevant information in the question upfront :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, yea i could have included all upfront, but i cant get better if i dont try myself first :)

Answer (score 0):

This will count the number of distinct names, having more than one distinct value:

```
Names with Multiple Distinct Values = 
COUNTROWS ( 
    FILTER ( 
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS ( 
            MyTable[Name], 
            "Distinct Values", 
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( MyTable[Values] )
        ),
        [Distinct Values] > 1
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this one was unable to count correctly.

Comment: Hmm, interesting, I might have done something wrong. In that case, what is "MyTable[Values]" ?   I thought that it referred to the "filter" column.

Comment: Yes, it does. You may need to be careful with which filters you apply to the measure... but it works. See worked example: https://pwrbi.com/so_56426646/

Comment: Broken link, but i really appreciate your help too!  I have no doubt it works, but it might be some issues when i apply it to the bigger data model i have